# TSLint is only running for files in the root folder of a "Blank Node.js Web Application" project

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-2015, tslint

I have a *TypeScript Blank Node.js Web Application* project in Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (this project type is found under TypeScript/Node.js), and I'm using TSLint as part of my workflow. To the best of my knowledge, TSLint is built-in for this version of VS.

I have another project in my solution, *HTMLAppProject*, which is a *HTML Application with TypeScript* project (this project type is found under TypeScript directly).

This is how the solution is laid out:

```
Solution
|-- NodeJSProject
|   |-- lib
|   |   |-- class1.ts
|   |   `-- class2.ts
|   `-- app.ts
|-- HTMLAppProject
|   |-- lib
|   |   `-- class.ts
|   `-- app.ts
`-- tslint.json
```

TSLint is running and showing warnings correctly for all files in *HTMLAppProject*, and it recognizes the *tslint.json* file in the solution root folder.

However, it only works for the *app.ts* file in *NodeJSProject* -- it's not doing anything for *NodeJSProject/lib/class1.ts* and *NodeJSProject/lib/class2.ts*. That is:

```
Solution
|-- NodeJSProject
|   |-- lib
|   |   |-- class1.ts // <- no TSlint
|   |   `-- class2.ts // <- no TSlint
|   `-- app.ts
|-- HTMLAppProject
|   |-- lib
|   |   `-- class.ts
|   `-- app.ts
`-- tslint.json
```

Could this be a bug perhaps? (it is reproducible using the above directory layout)

---

I tried adding *tslint.json* to individual project directories instead, no effect, still not running for files that are not in the project root directory. I also tried the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38265048/2788872), no effect, it doesn't seem to be an encoding issue.

Comment: Dumb question, but have to ask... Does `NodeJSProject/app.ts` import any of the classes in `NodeJSProject/lib`?

Comment: @SunilD. That's actually a relevant question IMO. However, I just tried doing an `import` in the above layout, no effect. So we can rule that out (also, TSLint runs for files in _HTMLAppProject_ even without any imports).